# How to subclass Pygal graphs

Tags: python, pygal

I'm looking at subclassing the XY graph in Pygal, as I want to try override some of the Graph's methods such as `_x_axis`and `_y_axis`.

```
import pygal
from pygal.style import Style, CleanStyle

class CustomXY(pygal.XY):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomXY, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def  _x_axis(self):
        pass
    def  _y_axis(self):
        pass

scatter = CustomXY(stroke=False, show_y_guides=False, truncate_legend=20)
```

When I try to run this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygal_test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    scatter = CustomXY(stroke=False, show_y_guides=False, truncate_legend=20)
  File "pygal_test2.py", line 6, in __init__
    super(CustomXY, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygal/ghost.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.cls = REAL_CHARTS[name]
KeyError: 'CustomXY'
```

Replacing `CustomXY(pygal.XY)` with  `CustomXY(pygal.graph.xy.XY)` gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygal_test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    scatter = CustomXY(stroke=False, show_y_guides=False, truncate_legend=20)
  File "pygal_test2.py", line 6, in __init__
    super(CustomXY, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygal/graph/line.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(Line, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stroke'
```

What is the preferred way to subclass Pygal graphs?

Answer (score 0):

It is an open source project, is there a particular reason you don't want to make the changes in your own fork version of XY?

http://pygal.org/

We all see the see that banner in the top right... right?

In all seriousness I am a little thrown off by the class  [Ghost](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/blob/master/pygal/ghost.py) throwing this error in its **init** considering that Ghost isn't in the object Hierarchy for your new class.

pygal looks like a cool package and I'm interested in what others people have to say here.

Comment: When you want to subclass, you create a subclass.
When you want to change the base class, **then** you fork and change the base class.
There are two distinct and different use-cases.

Comment: @kpie That is really a comment rather than an answer.
Of course I fork it but then I am maintaining a fork + my application instead of just my application.